# python の NamedTuple で一部のフィールドだけ変更した値を作成したい

Tags: python, python3

例えば、以下のような NamedTuple があったとします。

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Enemy(NamedTuple):
  name: str
  power: int
  defense: int

slime = Enemy(name='slime', power=1, defense=1)
```

このとき、 slime から defense を １０倍にした rare_slime を作ろうとしたとき、効率良い方法は何でしょうか？  NamedTuple は、基本 immutable (value object) であるので、単にコピー・代入するのはうまくいかなさそうなので、質問しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

的はずれな回答であればすみません。メソッド `_replace()` がよいのではないかと思いますが、 `_replace()` 以外で探されていますか？

```py
rare_slime = slime._replace(defense=slime.defense * 10)
```

あるいは、 `_replace()` よりも速いものがあるのではないか、というご質問でしょうか。いかがでしょう。

参考:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace

Comment: ドキュメントをちゃんと読もう、と言う話ですね。。